# TalkBack, how to figure out what the non-text-reading sounds mean

Tags: swype, accessibility, talk-back, custom-sounds

I am trying to use TalkBack without looking at the screen, but even when I look I am not good with sounds because they distract me and I cannot figure out what they mean.

So, is there a resource, somewhere, which tells me, as a TalkBack help location, what the various sounds mean, so a blind person can know what they are and how to move their fingers I the touchscreen?

Furthermore, oes a keyboard like Swype reissue its own TalkBack sounds, or do these sounds come from TalkBack itself?

I either case, how do I go about, possibly blindly, figuring out what the various sounds mean?

Thanks..